# Getting $P^1$ by the sphere $S^1$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider $S^1=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2: \lVert x\rVert=1\right\}$. Now let $P^1$ be obtained from $S^1$ by identifying antipodal points.

I have the following questions:

1) How can I imagine $P^1$? I do not have an idea how I can imagine in in order to get an impression how it looks like.

2) What could be meant by $[x,-x]\in P^1$?

3) An element $x\in S^1$ can be written as $x=e^{i\phi}$. Is there a similar way to write an element of of $P^1$ in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

You can image it as a $S^{1}$.

Note that if you have $S^{1}$ and identify all points except those intersecting the $y$ axis you get a half circle. Then you need to identify the points that intersect the $y$ axis closing the circle again.

The notation refers to the fact that your points are not points in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$  but equivalence classes of points in $S^{1}$ identify by antipodal points.

Yes, because as I said the new space is basically $S^{1}$.

You might also be interested in this [question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311196/homeomorphism-between-the-real-projective-line-and-a-circle)

Comment: Does it have a special reason to characterize the points on $P^1$ by $e^{i2\theta}$?

Comment: Not that I am aware.