Topology of the projective space
I am studying the fundamental group and I am facing a problem with the projective space: we know that, by definition, the real projective space $P^m(\mathbb{R})$ is the quotient of $R^{m+1}-\{0\}$ under the equivalence relation $x\sim \lambda x\, \forall \lambda \neq 0$, that is the action of the multiplicative group of the non null real numbers. But the projective space is also homeomorphic to the quotient of the sphere $S^m$ under the equivalence relation induced by the antipodal map $\alpha(x)=-x$, that is the action of the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ on the sphere.
However, I know that the projective real line is homeomorphic to $S^1$, because the projective line is homeomorphic to the Alexandroff compactification of $\mathbb{R}$, which is homeomorphic to $S^1$.
Thus, my question is: why the projective real line is not the quotient of $S^1$ under the equivalence relation induced by the antipodal map? Why this holds just for $m\geq 2$?
Thanks for any answer and help!

The real protective line is indeed the quotient of $S^1$ under the equivalence relation induced by the antipodal map, see here

Thank you for your interesting question. In the future, consider splitting the written material into paragraphs. It will help communicate the information about your prior knowledge and work, and also your actual question better.

Both can be true! The quotient of $S^1$ by the antipodal map is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4507224.


Why is the projective real line not the quotient of $S^1$ under the equivalence relation induced by the antipodal map?

It is! It is also homeomorphic to $S^1$, as you correctly observe. Perhaps it is surprising at first sight that the quotient of $S^1$ by the antipodal action is just $S^1$ again, in particular since this is not true for all higher-dimensional spheres, but showing that this is the case is actually rather straightforward point-set topology. In case you don't want to work this out yourself (although I recommend it), this has been done a number of times on this site alone. Here's an answer of mine that gives a fair amount of detail, for instance.
