# $\mathbb R \mathbb P^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$. Question about the proof.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

$\mathbb R \mathbb P^1$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ by identifying antipodal points. This is pretty clear to me. But my question is: Why are we allowed to identify antipodal points? Because if we do so, then we no longer have $S^1$ as the homeomorphic space, but a quotient space. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is $\Bbb RP^1$?

Comment: Why would you assume that $S^{1}$, a circle is hoemeomorphic to $\Bbb{RP}^{1}$? Ofcourse $\Bbb{RP}^{1}$ is homeomorphic to the quotient and not $S^{1}$. In fact many books define $\Bbb{RP}^{1}$ in that way.

Comment: This quotient of $S^1$ is indeed homeomorphic to $S^1.$

Comment: Here is a good way to see it in my opinion: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4730545/1101015

Comment: Your question "Why are we allowed to identify antipodal points?" is too imprecise and lacking to much context to be answerable.

Comment: Do you think that just because the real line is homeomorphic to itself, that it cannot be homeomorphic to the interval (0, ∞) ?